# Disable image paste in RichTextBox in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

We have an UserControls which herits from the `RichTextBox`. We would like to forbid the user to enter any image(with copy paste) in this user control.

I found several places where speaking of this:

- [This doesn't work with Winforms](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0f762cb8-7383-4937-8ee8-f8df5d3a9852/disable-image-paste-in-richtextbox)
- [This will not work when doing a right-click -> Paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511984/how-to-prevent-richtextbox-to-paste-images-within-it)

Currently I've this solution:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == (Keys)Shortcut.CtrlV || keyData == (Keys)Shortcut.ShiftIns)
    {
        if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Which works for copy paste with CTRL+C-CTRL+V, but not with the contextual menu.

**EDIT**

I tried the given proposition:

```
public class CustomRichBox : RichTextBox
{
    private const int WM_PASTE = 0x0302;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_PASTE )
        {
            if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

But when I do the CTRL+V, I don't receive this message

Comment: Not a proper answer, but here are some suggestions on how to do this with unmanaged MFC rich edit controls: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250759/how-does-a-cricheditctrl-know-a-paste-operation-has-been-performed and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104809/en-protected-and-richedit.  Maybe you could try to make use of this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to override the `WndProc` method to filter the `WM_PASTE` message:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    // Trap WM_PASTE with image:
    if (m.Msg == 0x302 && Clipboard.ContainsImage())
    {
        return;
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

**EDIT**
Unfortunatly, this approach won't work because the `RichTextBox` control doesn't send the `WM_PAINT` message to itself. See also: [Detecting if paste event occurred inside a rich text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618162/detecting-if-paste-event-occurred-inside-a-rich-text-box).

Comment: Well, regarding the link you gave: The first solution doesn't work with the contextual menu. And basing something on the length feels just dirty. I mean we have some model bound on those texts, so if the model change its values and reflects this on the RichTextBox, it will be detected as a paste

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there is no global Paste-Event, on which you can subscribe like in WPF. But maybe this is a solution for you:

[hook on default "Paste" event of WinForms TextBox control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446233/hook-on-default-paste-event-of-winforms-textbox-control)

This worked for me.

Comment: This should capture Ctrl+V and the Contextual menu -> paste ? Or only the second one?

Comment: This should work for both. I tried out with success.

Comment: It's weird, I copy pasted their code(see my edit) but when I do ctrl+V, it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, you are absolutely right. This only works for TextBox. I tried again and it also doesn't work. Is there any way to choose TextBox instead of RichTextBox?

Answer (score 0):

As a quick workaround, I tried to copy only the Text (using RichTextBox.Text) in another RichTextBox, then copy the Rtf string in the first RichTextBox, all of that in the "TextChanged" event. However there are a lot of downsides for this workaround. First: is not optimized, second and most important: you lose all text formatting, which might be the reason you chose RichTextBox in the first place, and third: you can still see the image for one or two frames in the RTB until it disappears, and if the user is writing a large text it isn't working very smoothly (but fortunately you can fix this if you copy-paste the code in paste events). However, it turned out to be very useful in my app, which is the reason I posted this answer here.
So here is all the code (assuming you have a RichTextBox named RTB and an auxiliary RichTextBox named auxRTB):

```
    private void RTB_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int selStart = RTB.SelectionStart;
        int selLenght = RTB.SelectionLength;
        auxRTB.Text = RTB.Text;
        RTB.TextChanged -= RTB_TextChanged;
        RTB.Rtf = string.Copy(auxRTB.Rtf);
        RTB.TextChanged += RTB_TextChanged;
        try
        {
            RTB.SelectionStart = selStart;
            RTB.SelectionLength = selLenght;
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
```

Now, if you are interested, here I'm going to explain how is that useful in my app. So I built a command system, and the only reason I chose RichTextBox insted of normal TextBox is because I wanted to give different colors to each type of thing from a command. The commands are not meant to be long so I don't have any optimiziation problems, and I don't care about losing formatting, since I always change the colors automatically.

Edit: by the way, here are some links to the same problem on other sites, which might actually help you:

Link 1: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0f762cb8-7383-4937-8ee8-f8df5d3a9852/disable-image-paste-in-richtextbox?forum=wpf

Link 2: [C# / WPF: Richtextbox: Find all Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404516/c-sharp-wpf-richtextbox-find-all-images)

Link 3: https://thomaslevesque.com/2015/09/05/wpf-prevent-the-user-from-pasting-an-image-in-a-richtextbox/